# Change defaultCoreName though API

Tags: solr

In Solr 4.3 you can create, unload, etc. cores through [CoreAdmin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin). Is it possible to change the default core (`<cores defaultCoreName="...">`) through a similar API without restarting Solr?

Comment: Not sure if there is an core admin call to change the default core name. But you can try swap http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP to point the default core to the core you want.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be an easier way than SWAPping them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jayendra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/950178/jayendra) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16947846/369450#comment-24482021),

> Not sure if there is an core admin call to change the default core name. But you can try swap wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP to point the default core to the core you want.

Say the default core is set to *live*. You can swap the *live* core with another core such as *ondeck* using the [SWAP](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP) command:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=SWAP&core=live&other=ondeck
```

The old *live* core is now *ondeck* while the old *ondeck* core is the new *live* core.